# Windows Phone 7 navigation to internet from an application

Tags: windows-phone-7, hyperlink, navigation

I have the following question:
I have my Windows Phone 7 appplication and I have a `HyperlinkButton` with the `NavigateUri` binded to an `Uri` created like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://google/ro",UriKind.Ablosute)
```

but when I press the button I get the following error :

> Navigation is only supported to relative URIs that are fragments, or begin with '/', or which contain ';component/'.\r\nParameter name: uri

What did I do wrong? Or is the WP7 that does not allow to surf the internet from an application with a `HyperlinkButton`? Since when I create the uri like `Uri uri = new Uri("/Page.xaml",UriKind.Relative)` it redirects me to `Page.xaml` in the project.

Answer (score 34):

I found a rather strange workaround that fixes this. Just add a TargetName="_blank" property to your HyperlinkButton control, and it magically starts working.

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Google" NavigateUri="http://google.com" TargetName="_blank" />
```

Chris

Comment: This behaves similar to WebBrowserTask. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/98fefb30-a9f9-4a5f-9942-6965cb2f2e3c

Comment: Works for me too, strange :).

Comment: This is still applicable as of Sep 2014 for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight. Very odd!!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the phone navigation system to navigate to the web (where would you expect it to display?). But you can use the web browser control to display web pages in your app. See this [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dohollan/archive/2010/08/25/adventures-with-the-windows-phone-7-webbrowser-control.aspx)

You could also use a [Web Browser Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) something along the lines of

```
WebBrowserTask wtb = new WebBrowserTask();
wtb.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute); 
wtb.Show();
```

Comment: For clarity, you'd call like the above in the `Click` eventhandler for the hyperlinkbutton.

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` is obsolete. Use `Uri`, as below.

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserTask wtb = new WebBrowserTask();
    wtb.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute); 
    wtb.Show();         
}
```