# How to open a Hyperlink in WebBrowser control in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Hyperlink button and web browser as below

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Link}" 
                 Content="{Binding Path=Title}" TargetName="webBrowser1"/>
<phone:WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,12"  
                  Name="webBrowser1" Width="456" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                  Navigated="webBrowser1_Navigated" />
```

I want to open the link in web browser when i click on Hyperlink button.But when i click on Hyperlink button the webpage is opening in a new page ,i want it to open in webbrowser control of same page .Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Should mostly be answered on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510689/windows-phone-7-navigation-to-internet-from-an-application including links to examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a handler to the click event of the HyperlinkButton.

In that event handler, call `Navigate()` on the WebBrowser control (passing the appropriate path).