# HTML parsing & navigation to webpage

Tags: c#

I am just learning HTML parsing but didn't get proper code to implement it for windows phone 8.1 for basics like displaying a picture from a webpage & also some content 
Also to navigate user to a particular webpage from my app..

Comment: So you want to know how to get a picture from the web and display it in a winphone app and you want to know how to embed a link your app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319817/download-an-image-from-url-and-opening-it-in-an-image-control-in-wp7

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510689/windows-phone-7-navigation-to-internet-from-an-application